# Cannot install libspatilite on macOS

Tags: spatialite

I'm trying to install the [spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) on macOS to query a sqlite db with geocordinates.

There is a brew formula that ships that lib and tools

```
brew install libspatialite
brew install spatialite-tools
```

I installed those but when I try to load the library I get this error:

```
spatialite test.db  'SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite")'
SpatiaLite version ..: 4.3.0a   Supported Extensions:
    - 'VirtualShape'    [direct Shapefile access]
    - 'VirtualDbf'      [direct DBF access]
    - 'VirtualXL'       [direct XLS access]
    - 'VirtualText'     [direct CSV/TXT access]
    - 'VirtualNetwork'  [Dijkstra shortest path]
    - 'RTree'       [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
    - 'MbrCache'        [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
    - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
    - 'VirtualElementary'   [ElemGeoms metahandler]
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
    - 'VirtualFDO'      [FDO-OGR interoperability]
    - 'VirtualGPKG' [OGC GeoPackage interoperability]
    - 'VirtualBBox'     [BoundingBox tables]
    - 'SpatiaLite'      [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 version ......: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016
GEOS version ........: 3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6
LWGEOM version ......: 2.1.5
TARGET CPU ..........: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0
Error: dlopen(mod_spatialite, 10): image not found
```

I did have this installed on my previous mac and it was working just fine.

`brew doctor` looks ok as well:

```
brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

And the dynamic library is present:

```
brew list libspatialite
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/include/spatialite/ (19 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/include/spatialite.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/lib/libspatialite.7.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/lib/mod_spatialite.7.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/lib/pkgconfig/spatialite.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/libspatialite/4.3.0a_3/lib/ (3 other files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify a full filename for the module in SQL:

```
SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite.dylib")
```

or

```
SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite.7.dylib")
```